# How to make such custom list/collection

Tags: c#, list, collections, ienumerable

I'm trying to develop a custom collection or list class which provides me the following capabilities:

```
Add(MyObject)
Add(MyObject, String)   ' key
Remove(MyObject)
RemoveByKey(String) ' key
RemoveAt(Index)
Count
Clear
Item(Index)
Item(String)    ' key
Contains(MyObject)
ContainsKey(String) ' key
GetEnumerator   ' for-each MyObject
```

I've searched through IEnumerable, IList, ICollection but none are satisfying what I need above. For example, they're all missing storing of objects by Key(string).
How do I create such a collection/list object? I've noticed that the best thing that matches my requirements is the ListViewItemCollection object available by the system. I wish I could see the coding inside it to find out how it has implemented the storing and retrieval of objects.

Can anybody help out? Or guide me to tutorial links.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you want a dictionary.

Comment: to add to @SLaks comment, Microsoft provides the source code to their implementation of `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` here: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs

Comment: This looks more like an `OrderedDictionary` though, as he wants to access items by index too.

Comment: I would combine two containers - Dictionary for those with Key and List for all of them. Is Index related to Key?

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: No; `OrderedDictionary` does not have an indexer.

Comment: @SLaks easy to confuse with `SortedDictionary`, the ordered one just maintains the order in which items are added: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @AnthonyRussell ICollection would not provide me the Key access. I could use the Dictionary, but how would i manage the GetEnumerator? I don't want to pass on the KeyPair to the user when he does for-each loop. I only want my custom object (MyObject) to be passed on in it.

Comment: @C.Evenhuis: Don't use non-generic collections.

Comment: @SLaks I did not advise to use `OrderedDictionary`, I compared `Dictionary` with what he is looking for. I'm not trying to attack your comment, just trying to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of such class could be System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection which is implemented like `List<KeyValuePair<string,Control>>` (actually Control already contains the key) and `this[string]` is implemented using ordinary for-loop (linear searching for the key).

We can help to speed this up by adding Dictionary and add every item with key to both collection (List+Dictionary). Items without key are added to List only.

**EDIT:** Further improvement may use `List<KeyValuePair<string,T>>` and `Dictionary<string,KeyValuePair<int,T>>` - mapping index from List to Dictionary for faster removing. RemoveAt should check if the key is preset and delete it from dictionary as well. RemoveByKey can get index for internal List.RemoveAt.

**ADDON based on comments:** implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` may look like this:

```
class MyObjectList<T>: IEnumerable<T> {
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator() {
    T[] a = items; int n = size;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        yield return a[i]; }
IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() {
    return GetEnumerator(); }
```

...the above are internals of `List<T>`

**ADDON:** [here you can see my custom ListCore](http://pastebin.com/hMhbqNSW) and [List created from it](http://pastebin.com/Yj9wmpz8) (feel free to use it as you wish).

Comment: Speed is not an issue. The collection I'm trying to develop won't be keeping more than 50 items I suppose. But isn't it a burden on memory to keep an object in a dictionary and a list ?

Comment: Well if speed is not an issue then I would go the same way as ControlCollection. But I like to optimize for speed and memory overhead won't be that big (like *2 or *3 - that sould not be a problem, speed may).

Comment: So let me get this straight. I use an internal List and Dictionary to manage the Add, Remove, RemoveAt, RemoveByKey, etc. But for GetEnumerator, I believe I need to implement some interface. Should it be IList or IColelction or something else?

Comment: GetEnumerator is enought, but you *should* add `IEnumerable<T>` interface. GetEnumerator() is simple : `foreach(KeyValuePair<string,T> pair in innerList) yield return pair.Value;`

Comment: I examined your @firda ListCore  example along with few other custom collections source code I found on the net, I noticed many custom collections are using Array to handle their work instead of relying on the built-in interfaces like IList or ICollection. Is the performances on these interfaces really bad that one has to resort to manually managed arrays?

Comment: I've managed to create a custom collection. Have a look. It does work fine for me. But the only thing that's bothering me is that is it memory efficient way to do it or not. [check here](http://pastebin.com/T1HZVmV2)

Comment: About my ListCore: I needed collection than can move elements (not swap, but reorder). Not a standard feature of flat list. So, one day, I created that. About memory: Dictionary is a bit memory overhead, but ask yourself: wich methods are gonna be used the most? Search by key or enumeration?

Answer (score 2):

I bet there are tons of easier ways to do this, but here's one approach. You could create a `struct` containing the key and value of each item:

```
public sealed class Listionary<K, T> : IDictionary<K, T>, IList<T>
{
    private struct ListionaryPair
    {
        public ListionaryPair(T item) : this()
        {
            Item = item;
        }

        public ListionaryPair(K key, T item) : this()
        {
            Key = key;
            Item = item;
        }

        public K Key { get; private set; }
        public T Item { get; private set; }
        public bool HasKey { get; private set; }
    }

    private readonly List<ListionaryPair> list = new List<ListionaryPair>();
```

(The whole `HasKey` thing allows value types as `K`, or `null` references as valid keys. If you only want `string` keys you could replace this struct with `KeyValuePair<string, T>`)

And then both interfaces separately:

```
    public void Add(T item)
    {
        list.Add(new ListionaryPair(item));
    }

    public void Add(K key, T item)
    {
        list.Add(new ListionaryPair(key, item));
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        list.RemoveAt(index);
    }
```

You can hide ugly methods by explicitly implementing them:

```
    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<K, T>>.CopyTo(KeyValuePair<K, T>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        // code implementing the method
    }
```

You'll need some helper methods for access by key:

```
    private int IndexOfKey(K key)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
        {
            var pair = list[i];
            if (pair.HasKey && pair.Key == key)
            {
                return i;
            }
        }

        return -1;
    }
```

but if you get them right the rest won't be that much of a challenge:

```
    public T this[K key]
    {
        get
        {
            int index = IndexOfKey(key);
            if (index < 0)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }

            return list[index].Item;
        }
        set
        {
            int index = IndexOfKey(key);
            if (index < 0)
            {
                throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
            }

            list[index] = new ListionaryPair(key, value);
        }
    }
```

It's quite a bit of coding to complete each interface method, but most will be short and simple. You'll have to decide whether you allow multiple items with the same key, whether `IDictionary<,>.Clear()` clears the entire collection or only keyed items, etc.

Also there's no backing `Dictionary` in this example, so performance might not be that great.

Comment: `public interface IDictionary<TKey, TValue> : ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>, IEnumerable` ...so, I would rather stick with KeyValuePair and using null for no key. ...but +1 for the efforts (nice and long answer).